# Gitlab standalone installation failed

Tags: gitlab, ubuntu-server

I'm using

- Ubuntu 18.04 server

Trying to install **Gitlab standalone** using [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-configure-gitlab-on-ubuntu-18-04) blog and [official](https://about.gitlab.com/installation/#ubuntu) one too

> I am getting the below error:-

```
Running handlers:
There was an error running gitlab-ctl reconfigure:

bash[migrate gitlab-rails database] (gitlab::database_migrations line 49) had an error: Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed: Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20180927-7185-157g8fm" ----
STDOUT: rake aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/opt/gitlab/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-rails/lib/tasks/gitlab/db.rake:51:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/opt/gitlab/embedded/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => gitlab:db:configure
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
STDERR: 
---- End output of "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20180927-7185-157g8fm" ----
Ran "bash"  "/tmp/chef-script20180927-7185-157g8fm" returned 1

Running handlers complete
Chef Client failed. 4 resources updated in 01 minutes 21 seconds
```

> I thought I was messing up with the URL.

```
$grep "external" /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb | head -n 3
##! For more details on configuring external_url see:
##! https://docs.gitlab.com/omnibus/settings/configuration.html#configuring-the-external-url-for-gitlab
external_url 'http://192.168.4.215'
```

I tried varius options for **external_url** like

- IP address
- domain name

Let me know what is going wrong.

Comment: I had the same problem and this workaround here helped me:https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/3744

Do:
`sudo systemctl disable gitlab-runsvdir`
`sudo systemctl enable gitlab-runsvdir`
`sudo gitlab-ctl restart`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem and found a workaround here:

[gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/3744](http://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/omnibus-gitlab/issues/3744)

Doing the following steps solved the problem:

```
sudo systemctl disable gitlab-runsvdir
sudo systemctl enable gitlab-runsvdir
sudo gitlab-ctl restart
```